# Find current NT Kernel Logger

Tags: c, windows, logging, etw

I'm looking at the Event Tracing for Windows API and, according to the documentation and some tests I've ran, it seems like if there is already a kernel logger running, the API sends a **ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS** when calling [StartTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364117(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you call [ControlTrace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363696(v=vs.85).aspx) with **EVENT_TRACE_CONTROL_QUERY**, you can get the thread id of the current logging session, but since the launching of a session is handled by the Windows kernel, I always get a thread id that belongs to System Process (PID=4).

My question is: can you find who *really* launched that logging session?

Thanks!

Comment: so... it's been a while, but did you had any luck on solving this?
I have the same question. Saw some code here and there that simply closes the tracer session, without knowing anything from it :)

Answer (score 0):

"can you find who really launched that logging session?"
As you said it is launched by the system process. The System process starts monitoring the kernel level file, disk , process activites and so enables th NT Kernel logger session.If its launched already then you can suck out events from it , no point on knowing who launched the session..I guess.

Comment: Ok. But if you want to launch a kernel logging session it could be useful to know who you are stopping.

Comment: Not sure how to do that.....but if you create a consumer of your own you can simply stop your consumtion at any point of time and not close the NT kernel session(if it was not started by you).

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that you can have more than one NT Kernel Logger session? Because everything I've read so far says otherwise.

Comment: There is only one NT kernel logger session (period). All I am saying is that you can stop your event consumtion without stopping the kernel session.

Comment: Exactly. But this question is about finding who is currently running the logging session so that we don't kick him out. Because before starting I _need_ to make sure that I'm not stopping any important processes.